Extended ASCII character from Omron NJ PLC to Sato printer
I am using an Omron NJ PLC, with which I send a string to a Sato printer using TCP socket communication. I can print 'normal' text by sending ASCII characters, but when I want to print something like a copyright icon, the Sato printer does not print it.
I created a layout with Nicelabel, and used the code that you can save to a text file in my PLC. Nicelabel displays text as ASCII, so hex 4E is 'N'. A copyright icon is hex A9, but Nicelabel places an Ã in front of it. This is an unusual Sato command that I cannot use. My question is, what is Ã? How can I print extended ASCII characters with a Sato printer? The font I am using should support these characters. When using the Sato Beta Bold font, it does not print the entire text string if it contains a copyright icon. With the SATO CG Sleek font, it prints a '?' instead.
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This looks like a codepage issue. Most people assume a Unicode code page wherein the copyright symbol would indeed be U+00A9, or commonly 0xA9. The symbol you mention Ã appears to be formally called "Latin Letter A with Tilde". This is U+00C3. I suspect the printer is assuming some unexpected code page whereas most people are used to Unicode or maybe Windows-1252.
